# Copying Double Pointer Strings

Tags: c, string, pointers

Assume I have `char **argv`, so that `argv[0] = some string` and `argv[1] = another string` etc...

I have another double pointer string array in a struct, call it `s1->argv` also defined as `char **argv` within the struct.

I am trying to copy `argv` into `s1->argv1`. I tried `malloc`ing `s1->argv` to something with a max value (so 7 strings, each string of max 100 chars) and using `strcpy` but that obviously does not work. It only ends up copying `argv[0]`. This is how I used it: `strcpy(*s1->argv, *argv)`

How can I preserve each index of the array too?

Comment: Any reason not to do `s->argv = argv` in `main`? Do you want to modify the copy?

Comment: Not really... but I might have to pass it to some other functions. Would that still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below makes a copy of `argc` and `argv` arguments of `main` into user defined structure. The copy is exactly the same as original arguments (`argv` is terminated by `NULL` as in main). This code does not handle any abnormal events (like malloc failures, signal interruption etc.).

You may want to avoid casting the result of `malloc` (it is not required in C), there is a lot of debate whether this casting is a good or bad thing. The choice is yours. I value portability more, so I choose to cast, compile with all warnings enabled and eliminate all of them in the code (see the comments to this answer).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct my_struct
{
    int    argc;
    char** argv;
};

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    int    i = 0;
    size_t n = 0;
    struct my_struct s;

    memset(&s,0,sizeof(s));
    s.argc = argc;
    /* alloc one more element than 'argc' to terminate 's.argv' with NULL */
    s.argv = (char**)malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    /* terminate 's.argv' with NULL exactly as 'argv' in 'main' */
    s.argv[argc] = NULL; 
    for(i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        n = strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
        s.argv[i] = (char*)malloc(n);
        strcpy(s.argv[i],argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another option for copying the strings in `argv` could be using `strdup` function, then you could replace the three lines:

```
n = strlen(argv[i]) + 1;
s.argv[i] = (char*)malloc(n);
strcpy(s.argv[i],argv[i]);
```

with

```
s.argv[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
```

Comment: This is just an example, not intercontinental missle control code. If malloc failes, then you can (in most cases) only abort. What if your machine is hit by a meteorite while executing the code ?

Comment: I don't think the C standard covers meteorite impact.  :)

Comment: Not yet, but I suspect the guys from C++ standardization committe may be already working on it :)

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` unless you're writing C++.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: I know that you don't have to do it, but not doing it does not necessary means it is a good thing. When you are casting pointers explicitly and compiling with '-Wall' (gcc) it helps to avoid many nasty errors. Moreover, it makes your intensions clear to the reader(s) of your code.

Comment: There is a lot of arguments for and against this practice. I am on the 'against' side. non-casting the result of malloc is not an absolute truth - it all depends what you value more (e.g. portability vs readability). You can see clearly the debate in the post that you sent the link to.

Comment: Casting has nothing to do with portability. Portability is about libraries across platforms, not between C++ and C, which are two different languages (which share some syntactic similarities).

Comment: That is your opinion on the subject of portability. What about compatibility with older compilers ? If you do not loose anything (maybe a litle bit of readability) then what is the problem with this (almost religious) belief about casting. BTW: I read everything in the post that you sent the link to. The guy is WRONG in quite a few points (I veryfied it myself - independent thinking is a good thing).

Comment: Your answer is wrong or at least highly questionable in several respects. I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you just want to copy the entire `argv` into another `char**` value.  If so then do the following

```
char** copy_all(char** argv, int length) {
  char** ppDest = malloc(sizeof(char**) * length);
  if (!ppDest) {
    return NULL;
  }

  int i = 0;
  for (i < length; i++) {
    char* pCurrent = argv[i];
    size_t currentLength = strlen(pCurrent);
    ppDest[i] = malloc(currentLength + 1);
    if (!ppDest[i]) {
      goto Error;
    }
    strcpy(ppDest[i], argv[i]);
  }

  return ppDest;

Error:
  while (i > 0) {
    free(ppDest[i - 1]);
    i--;
  }
  free(ppDest);
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You might want to `malloc` `currentLength` **+1** bytes for `ppDest[i]`.

Comment: @AusCBloke doh, the number of times I docked students for that mistake and I still can't but help make it myself